# How to calculate the best ratio so image fits into its container?

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, image-processing

I have a container of dimensions:

**container.width, container.height**

and I have a picture of dimensions:

**picture.width, picture.height**

My goal is to calculate the best ratio so picture fits into container (with no deformation)

whay would be the algorithm to get the ratio ?

```
picture.width*=ratio;
picture.height*=ratio;
```

(picture is already centered into the container)

Comment: The ratio always stays the same, the thing that changes is the length in the specified dimension

Answer (score 8):

Compute the scaling ratio as follows.

```
var ratio:Number = Math.min(
    container.width / picture.width,
    container.height / picture.height);
```

Then apply the scaling ratio uniformly to the picture to fit it within the container.

```
picture.scaleX = picture.scaleY = ratio;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 possibilities: either fit the picture's width to the container's width, or fit the picture's height to the container's height.  Try both.  For each, calculate the ratio needed to scale the dimension (width or height) you are fitting to the container, and use that to scale the picture's other dimension: if this causes that picture dimension to exceed the corresponding container dimension, then this possibility cannot work.

Exactly one of the two possibilities will work, unless the picture's aspect ratio equals the container's aspect ratio, in which case they both will (but then they will amount to the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
picture.width = container.width;
picture.scaleY = picture.scaleX;
if(picture.height > container.height)
{
    picture.height= container.height;
    picture.scaleX = picture.scaleY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that function which will return the scale of your picture :

```
function scaleRatio(cw:Number, ch:Number, pw:Number, ph:Number):Number
{
    return (ch / cw > ph / pw) ? cw / pw : ch / ph;
}
picture.scaleX = picture.scaleY = scaleRatio(container.width, container.height, picture.width, picture.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well If you don't mind the borders (eg: black borders for wide/landscape picture in square container etc)

Formula is: original width / original height * new width = aspect correct new height

In your case that would be:

`image.height = (image.width / image.height) * container.width;`

Alt version:

```
image.width = container.width; 
image.height = container.width / (image.width / image.height);
```